# Can newline-delimited fwrite()s be truncated partway through a line upon SIGINT/SIGKILL in PHP?

Tags: php, signals

Using plain `fopen(..., 'w')` and `fwrite()` in PHP, I'm writing simple `\n`-delimited lines of text to a file.

`strace` tells me that PHP is using `write()` to write the data to disk.

From [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (Linux):

> The number of bytes written may be less than count if, for example, there is insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the RLIMIT_FSIZE resource limit is encountered (see setrlimit(2)), or **the call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than count bytes.**

I'm not sure the best way to go about stress-testing this. I'm currently writing large batches of lines to a file and `SIGKILL`ing PHP midway through:

```php
<?php

$A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz';

$line = str_repeat("$A\n$A", 5000);

$fd = fopen('linebuf.txt', 'w');

for (;;) {
    
    fwrite($fd, $line);
    
    flush();
    
    print '.';
    
}
```

I used the following suboptimal hack to do the `SIGKILL`ing:

```sh
while :; do
  rm linebuf.txt
  timeout -s KILL 0.05 php linebuf.php
  [[ "$(tail -c 1 linebuf.txt)" != "z" ]] && break
done
```

Using the above, I found that the lines **always** seem to be fully complete - there are no partial writes.

***However,*** I get the impression I'm seeing "best case scenario" behavior, and that my script may well be susceptible to partial writes if it were to encounter SIGKILL and/or SIGINT.

(I'm not sure if PHP's own buffering is relevant in this picture, but I did find [a comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-write-buffer.php#122748) on the `stream_set_write_buffer()` doc page noting that the function does not work on files, referencing an 18-year old bug. I also discovered that the function returns `-1` in my own testing.)

---

**Further context/rationale**

I'm currently working on a backend script that loads a bunch of data from a slow-to-read data source. Iterating on this script is painfully slow: it currently takes around ~20 minutes to run (and that's before I tackle writing the part of the script that will actually process the data!).

The exceedingly obvious solution is to cache loaded data into a JSON or text file, then reread that (sequentially, at hundreds of MB/s) upon reload. Yes please.

However, the output of this particular script will affect everything else in the pipeline I'm building, so the integrity of the cache must be the same as the data source I'm reading from.

Elsewhere in this pipeline I frequently create temporary files then (close and) rename them into place (and delete all temporary files upon reload). Within this model, I might regenerate a few things, but I can reasonably prove (assuming sane hardware and environment) that I'll never see partially-written data.

I'm looking for a pattern that will allow me to maintain a similar level of correctness/confidence in a journaling/file-append context.

---

(As an aside, I've seen a few scenarios where multi-threaded programs and/or multiple separate processes fight over stdout in a terminal, or kernel threads and userspace processes trip over each other in dmesg.

In such circumstances it seems very easy for output from one process to be mixed in with output from another, on the same line. I think this is occurring at the block size boundaries?)

Comment: Maybe something like a queue of work (RabbitMQ for example) where each part of the process can be atomic.  Any failure in each part of the process should be re-runnable and so that a failure will start that part again (using ack with the queue process - or lack of).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. The two considerations that come to mind are complexity and speed - if (only) I can figure out sane file I/O, I don't have to launch (and manage) any daemons for the pipeline to run, and reload time is only limited by how fast I can parse the cached data straight off disk (eg, no connection/unmarshaling library overhead).

Comment: FWIW, part of the reason for posting this question is because my brain is having one of those elegance-vs-"ends justify means" fights with the idea of putting a checksum before each line written to the file, and discarding (without aborting) invalid lines, which would work here because whatever is corrupted would just be reloaded from the data store. I'm just trying to figure out if there are any more efficient approaches (with less overhead) than a few hundred thousand rounds of SHA256...